# EWMA covariance matrix using risk metrics methodology

Tags: pandas

Is there any tool in python that can help me do it. R seems to have so many packages that seem to be accomplishing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ewm.cov`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.EWM.cov.html) in pandas.  You can [specify](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html) the smoothing factor in terms of halflife, span, or center of mass.

In pandas 0.19, the result is a Panel.  In pandas 0.20, you'll get a MultiIndex DataFrame because Panel is deprecated.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 3))
covs = df.ewm(span=60).cov()
covs[3] # covariance matrix as of period 4; could be DatetimeIndex
Out[7]: 
         0        1        2
0  0.48489  0.12341 -0.41335
1  0.12341  0.59947 -0.18762
2 -0.41335 -0.18762  0.67513
```

Comment: Thanks brad. Does the recursion of ewma start at the top row of the dataframe or at the bottom. This has an impact on setting back test data

Comment: Starts at first position.  You want `.ewm(adjust=False)` (the default is `True`).  You may want to have a look at the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#exponentially-weighted-windows) to be sure for yourself.